# .csv not a SequenceFile Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks

While creating External table with partition in hive using spark in csv format `com.databricks.spark.csv` it works fine but I can't able to open the table created in hive which is in `.csv` format from hive shell

ERROR

```
hive> select * from output.candidatelist;

Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: hdfs://10.19.2.190:8020/biometric/event=ABCD/LabName=500098A/part-00000-de39bb3d-0548-4db6-b8b7-bb57739327b4.c000.csv not a SequenceFile
```

Code:

```
 val sparkDf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("nullValue", "null").schema(StructType(Array(StructField("RollNo/SeatNo", StringType, true), StructField("LabName", StringType, true)))).option("multiLine", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("hdfs://10.19.2.190:8020/biometric/SheduleData_3007_2018.csv")
sparkDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("path", "hdfs://10.19.2.190:8020/biometric/event=ABCD/").partitionBy("LabName").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").saveAsTable("output.candidateList")
```

how to access the table in Hive shell while the format of the table in csv

SHOW CREATE TABLE candidatelist;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `candidatelist`(
`col` array<string> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
 PARTITIONED BY (
 `centercode` string,
 `examdate` date)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('path'='hdfs://10.19.2.190:8020/biometric/output')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
 LOCATION

 'hdfs://nnuat.iot.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/sify_cvs_output.db/candidatelist-__PLACEHOLDER__'TBLPROPERTIES (
 'spark.sql.create.version'='2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292',
 'spark.sql.partitionProvider'='catalog',
 'spark.sql.sources.provider'='com.databricks.spark.csv',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='2',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"RollNo/SeatNo\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"LabName\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"Student_Name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"ExamName\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"ExamTime\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"Center\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"CenterCode\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"ExamDate\",\"type\":\"date\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='CenterCode',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'='ExamDate',
 'transient_lastDdlTime'='1535692379')
```

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, I define like `sparkDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("path", "hdfs://10.19.2.190:8020/biometric/event=ABCD/").partitionBy("LabName").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").saveAsTable("output.candidateList")` Spark code available in the question

Comment: How did you define the table **effectively, in the Hive Metastore** cf. `show create table` ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, Question Updated with `show create table`

Comment: As could be expected from the error message, the table has been defined to use `SequenceFile` format, not `TextFile` (i.e. CSV). Maybe that's the default in your specific Hive setup, and Spark does not handle that properly. Another case of Spark failing miserably.